# Encrypt Webclient data in c#

Tags: c#, encryption, model-view-controller, webclient, rest

I want to encrypt the JSON string and post using webclient.
I have a json string which I am passing to a RESTFUL API.
But, the problem here is I have already written the code in my project like below in all the files

```
obj = new WebClient();
Result = objWebClient.UploadString(API_Url ,JsonData_String);
```

and I don't want to go and change each webclient request in each file/Controller of my project because its a lot of work. I want to add the code to the centralized location so that all webclient method will access it.
So can I extend the UploadString method and add some mechanism that will encrypt the code before POST. If not how do I achieve this.

Also The API url is not in my control to use HTTPS.

Comment: Why not just use HTTPS on API url?

Comment: Yes I could have but the API url is not in my control. Thanks for the reply

Comment: Api url is in your code; of course it's under your control. If you're saying api doesn't support https at the server end, then get them to turn it on; it's simple and there is no excuse for not doing it. You don't even have to pay for ssl certificates any more. If they won't, then I fail to see how the api will understand your encrypted data so it's not a solution, unless someone will go to the effort of upgrading the api so it does (but you wouldn't bother, you'd just turn on https)

Comment: Where do you get the JSON data from? I suppose you're using something like Newtonsoft's JSON library. You could write a wrapper class which creates your JSON string via Newtonsoft but right before it returns it, you encrypt it. The receiver of your message needs to do the same, but in reverse order: decrypt and then call Newtonsoft. And you need to think about encryption algorithm (RSA/AES), key management and key exchange...

Answer (score 0):

You can write an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) of WebClient e.g. UploadStringEncrypted() then do a global search & replace in your source files to use your extension method.

```
static public class Ext
{
    static public void UploadStringEncrypted(this WebClient webClient, string url, string jsonData)
    {
        var encrypted = SomehowEncrypt(jsonData);
        webClient.UploadString(url, encrypted);     
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
obj = new WebClient();
Result = objWebClient.UploadStringEncrypted(API_Url ,JsonData_String);
```

Comment: Thanks of your reply.. How do I use this Ext class in my above line code

Comment: Added an example of usage.